# нужна помощь с sass mixin

Tags: html, css, sass

Проблема в следующем, я пытаюсь добавить mixin с помощью `=` и подключить с помощью `+`. Пытался с помощью `@mixin` `@include` (такой функции даже не видит)

при создании @mixin все компилируется как надо, но при присваивании этого же миксина выдает ошибку

```
=btn-hover
    &:hover
        background-image: none
        background-color: $main_color

.promo_btn 
    display: block 
    margin: 115px auto 0 auto 
    width: 259px 
    height: 63px 
    border: none 
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #1EACC7 0%, #4CE2FF 100%) 
    box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 
    border-radius: 4px 
    font-style: normal 
    font-weight: 400 
    font-size: 18px 
    line-height: 18px 
    text-transform: uppercase 
    color: $white_color
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21)
    +btn-hover
```

Вот ошибка

```
Error: Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'.
        on line 11 of sass/Users/1/my html front-end/uber/src/sass/style.sass, in mixin `btn-hover`  
        from line 140 of sass/Users/1/my html front-end/uber/src/sass/style.sass
>>     &:hover {

   ----^
```

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, где вы объявляете миксин и как и где вы его вызываете.

Comment: .promo_btn 
 display: block 
 margin: 115px auto 0 auto 
 width: 259px 
 height: 63px 
 border: none 
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #1EACC7 0%, #4CE2FF 100%) 
 box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 
 border-radius: 4px 
 font-style: normal 
 font-weight: 400 
 font-size: 18px 
 line-height: 18px 
 text-transform: uppercase 
 color: $white_color
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21)
    +btn_hover

Comment: Вы можете нажать `Править` и добавить код туда. Тот код, что вы добавили, там это проблемы нету.

Comment: Прошу прощения, редко пишу о какой либо проблеме, обычно решение всегда было на поверхности

Comment: Миксин назначается через [@mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

Comment: Я использовал mixin и include выдает следующее 'Error: invalid name in mixin definition
        on line 10 of sass/Users/1/my html front-end/uber/src/sass/style.sass
>> @mixin {

   ^'